# CSS class will not work due to some magic hidden digits

Tags: javascript, html, digit

I have a `<div>` with a `class` and want to assign a basic style to it. Somehow, my editor **Atom** seems to have messed up this code. I have copied and pasted

```
.my {
  background: yellow;
}
```

out of my editor, which does not work. Then I have added two other examples, which do work. The video below illustrates the problem:

https://vid.me/c2iB

While its easy to solve this, I got this problem in a second class, and I am interested, in how this error does occur. Does someone have an idea?

[**CODEPEN DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EZjWjy?editors=1100)

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pRJeRo?editors=1100

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The character you have after .my is not a space. It's a two bit character, with ASCII "194 160". Space is 032.

http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/ascii/

Comment: Thanks for the link! I was manually deleting characters to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 3):

There is some hidden character here

```
.my {
   ^
```

If you delete the space and remake it, it fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks :) combined with alexeys link I can track the error down inside Atom :)